# Selecting faces of a mesh based on vertices coordinates in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, mesh, matrix-indexing

I have two numpy arrays, one is for 3D vertices of a mesh, call it `vert` and one is for the triangular faces, call it `faces`:

The `vert` array is a `N x 3` shape array of `float`, hence N three dimensional points. The `x` coordinate of each point can have both positive and negative values.
As a pure example this can be the `vert` array:

```
[[  2.886495  24.886948  15.909558]
 [ -13.916695 -58.985245  19.655312]
 [ 40.415527   8.968353   8.515955]
 ...
 [ 13.392465 -58.20602   18.752457]
 [ -12.504704 -58.307934  18.912386]
 [ 13.322185 -58.52817   19.165733]]
```

Since the mesh is centered, the *left* part of the mesh is the one with positive x component and the corresponding vertex indices are found by a `np.where`

```
i_vert_left = np.where(vert[:,0]>0)[0]
```

I now would like to filter out those faces made of triangles with coordinates entirely in the positive `x` axis.

However I have a problem in doing this **indexing** operation correctly.
My first attempt was to subset the faces such that their corresponding vertices have `x>0`

```
faces_left = np.asarray([f for f in faces if np.all(np.isin(i_vert_left,f)) ])
```

but the operation is incredibly slow on large meshes.
How can I exploit a smart indexing of the faces?

Comment: What's `faces` like? Shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `faces` is a `Nx3` array of integers indexing the three vertices of each triangle, I think you should just need:

```
# Check whether each vertex is left or not
vert_left_mask = vert[:, 0] > 0
# Check whether each face has all vertices on left or not
faces_left_mask = np.all(vert_left_mask[faces], axis=1)
# Select resulting left faces
faces_left = faces[faces_left_mask]
```

The main "trick" here is in `vert_left_mask[faces]`, which replaces each integer vertex number with a boolean indicating whether the vertex is left or not, so it's easy to tell which face is fully left with `np.all`.